# Routes not matching in Rspec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

I can't seem to get a matching route in my rspec tests and I am not quite sure why.

routes.rb

```
resources :admins, only: [:index] do
  get 'configs', on: :collection, to: 'admins#configs'
end
```

Rspec response

```
Failure/Error: get '/admins/config'
     
ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches [GET] "/admins/config"
```

I run `rails routes | grep config` and this is the response so I think I am using the correct route

```
configs_admins GET /admins/configs(.:format) admins#configs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `'/admins/configs'` (plural) but you're trying to access `'/admins/config'` (singular).

Comment: Glad I could help :)